# Bubble chart with ggplot with no curcle

Tags: r, ggplot2

The data of df a I use is:

```
x   y   size
589 127 16,4724409449
465 58  21,0517241379
408 58  15,9137931034
```

I use this to take a bubble chart

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- read.csv("numbers.csv", header = TRUE)
ggplot(a,aes(x,y))+geom_point(size=a$size)
```

but in the chart I can't see any bubble. How can I make it?

Here is the dput of a data frame:

```
structure(list(x = c(589L, 465L, 408L), y = c(127L, 58L, 58L), 
    size = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("15,9137931034", 
    "16,4724409449", "21,0517241379"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "size"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Also if it possible to add names and different colours to every bubble?

```
 x  y   size name
    589 127 16,4724409449 nameA
    465 58  21,0517241379 nameB
    408 58  15,9137931034 nameC
```

Comment: may be because `size`  -- factor try to convert to numeric `a$size=as.numeric(as.character(gsub(",",".",a$size)))`

Comment: correct syntax is `geom_point(aes(size = size))`

Comment: @Batanichek thank you this solved my problem.

Comment: I think @mtoto variant also work and may be better for use

Comment: @Eracog An alternative way to solve the issue with `,` as decimal point, is to use the `dec` argument in `read.xyz` (i.e. `dec = ","`), when reading your file to R.

Comment: mtoto @Batanichek thank you both works for me. If you want to provide it as solution to accept it? Just a general question is it simple to add names for bubbles i.e. if I add a column in df named names and has nameA, nameB, nameC is it possible?

Comment: @Henrik this also works. Thank you. Please if anyone want to provide a solution in order to accept it?  Also if it possible to add names and different colours to every bubble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a bubble chart with size mapped to `a$size`, and colour and labels to `a$name`, we can try:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x, y, label = name)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = size, colour = name)) + 
  geom_text()
```